# Is there a way to search a console logged object for particular values in Chrome DevTools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'd like to console.log() an object and do a search for a particular value within that object. Is this possible?

*Note: the object that I'm trying to search is humongous and multi-dimensional, so expanding each field and doing a simple Ctrl+F find isn't ideal.*

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The code below adds something like what you're looking for to the console object as

`console.logSearchingForValue`

Breadth-first search, matching on equivalent "JSON" value, handling NaNs correctly, returning multiple locations, and making numeric index expressions not quoted are left as exercises to the reader. :)

It is already really easy to swap in different definitions of equality.

```
var searchHaystack = function(haystack, needle, path, equalityFn, visited) {

  if(typeof haystack != "object") {
    console.warn("non-object haystack at " + path.join("."));
  }

  if(visited.has(haystack))
    return [false, null];

  for(var key in haystack) {
    if(!haystack.hasOwnProperty(key))
      continue;

    if(equalityFn(needle, haystack[key])) {
      path.push(key);
      return [true, path];
    }

    visited.add(haystack);
    if(typeof haystack[key] == "object") {
      var pCopy = path.slice();
      pCopy.push(key);
      var deeper = searchHaystack(haystack[key], needle, pCopy, equalityFn, visited);
      if(deeper[0]) {
        return deeper;
      }
    }
  }
  return [false, null];
}

var pathToIndexExpression = function(path) {
   var prefix = path[0];
   path = path.slice(1);
   for(var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
      if(typeof path[i] == "string")
         path[i] = "\"" + path[i] + "\"";
   }
   return prefix + "[" + path.join("][") + "]"
}

console.logSearchingForValue = function(haystack, needle) {
   this.log("Searching");
   this.log(haystack);
   this.log("for");
   this.log(needle);
   var visited = new Set();
   var strictEquals = function(a,b) { return a === b; };
   var result = searchHaystack(haystack, needle, ["<haystack>"], strictEquals, visited);
   if(result[0]) {
      this.log("Found it!");
      this.log(pathToIndexExpression(result[1]));
   }
   else {
      this.log("didn't find it");
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you write that script? That's nuts (and awesome). I was hoping that there was a simple and native way to do it in devtools, but this works too. Thank you!

Comment: Nah, a stork just happened to drop it in my lap. :)  You're welcome.

Comment: I was going to start another post with this exact same question and this solution blew me away. This script is going in my TamperMonkey. Thank you so much.

Comment: So would you be using it to help reverse-engineer sites with non-trivial JS so that you can write Grease/TamperMonkey scripts?  That's pretty smart.

Comment: Here is small update to the script to prevent endless loop when cyclic object assignment https://gist.github.com/janmisek/63bd49106e27eea771f4

Comment: That's pretty cool.  I think I'll revisit this and add some of the "exercise for the reader" items...

Comment: I handled cyclic objects by using an ES6 Set, which should give decent performance even when searching very large objects.

Comment: This can't lookup keys? only strings?

Comment: `console.logSearchingForValue` looks for a field in `haystack` that is exactly equal (`===`) to `needle`.  If you wanted to find some object that just has a certain field name, you could use `searchHaystack` but use a different `equalityFn`

Comment: `var hasNeedleField = function(field,obj) { return field in obj; }` would work.

Comment: This is brilliant.

Answer (score 6):

1. Run (directly in console):

`JSON.stringify(myObject)`

this will output object as a string represantation.

2. Then do search in console by typing:

`Ctrl+f`

Comment: Heh. Good call. Much easier than the other answer.

Comment: it doesn't work if the object have circular structure